# Action Item's icon is not showing in action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add an `action item` to the `action bar` but the action item's icon is not showing.
XML file res/menu/actionbar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="test"
      android:showAsAction="always" />         

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />"
</menu>
```

Adding the `action bar`

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id)
    {
    case R.id.action_search:
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Action Button Pressed!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        return true;
    default: 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}



}
```

I have the `minimum sdk` in the `manifest file` set to 7

```xml
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Comment: There is a note on using the support library with menu items in the official tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems that you should read.

Comment: Before the line `inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);` inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` try using `menu.clear()`.

Comment: I have already read this guide, but only now i noticed the addition of `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` at the top of the xml file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for your menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
  android:title="test"
  app:showAsAction="always" />         

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
  android:title="@string/action_settings"
  app:showAsAction="never" />"
</menu>
```